# Teradata conversion to hive sql using case when

Tags: hive, teradata, case-when

I am trying to convert the below teradata sql to hive sql but I get empty table.

TERADATA SQL:

```
 SELECT              
 TRIM(CAST(BOOK_ID AS BIGINT)) || '_' ||TRIM(CAST(REF_ID AS BIGINT)) 
 AS BOOK_REF,
 CASE WHEN (PHOTO_COUNT > 0) AND (INDEX(PICTURE_URL , ';')>0) THEN 
 SUBSTRING(PICTURE_URL FROM 1 FOR POSITION(';' IN PICTURE_URL)-1)
 ELSE PICTURE_URL
 END AS MAIN_IMAGE 
                     
 FROM GENERIC_BOOKS;
```

HIVE :

```
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN (PHOTO_COUNT > 0) AND (instr(A.PICTURE_URL, ';') > 0) THEN 
 SUBSTRING(A.PICTURE_URL, 1, FIND_IN_SET(';', A.PICTURE_URL))-1
    ELSE A.PICTURE_URL
    END AS ITEM_MAIN_IMAGE
 FROM GENERIC_BOOKS;
```

PICTURE_URL for example :
[https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwWDE2A=/z/wKEAAOSwfURc~gng/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007;https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwW2MDA=/z/LQcAAOSwrzxc~gni/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007;https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwW2MDA=/z/XAIAAOSw7J1c~gnl/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007;https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwW2MDA=/z/aA8AAOSwYT1c~gnv/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007](https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwWDE2A=/z/wKEAAOSwfURc%7Egng/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007;https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwW2MDA=/z/LQcAAOSwrzxc%7Egni/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007;https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwW2MDA=/z/XAIAAOSw7J1c%7Egnl/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007;https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwW2MDA=/z/aA8AAOSwYT1c%7Egnv/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007)

For this example, the expected MAIN_IMAGE should be: [https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwWDE2A=/z/wKEAAOSwfURc~gng/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007](https://booking.com/00/s/OTAwWDE2A=/z/wKEAAOSwfURc%7Egng/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007)

Comment: please share generic_books ddl please, and sample teradata input and hive output be?

Comment: input & output of `SUBSTRING(PICTURE_URL FROM 1 FOR POSITION(';' IN PICTURE_URL)-1)`

Comment: I have updated the hive equivalent query for the mentioned teradata, If you could share the teradata input & output of the query in your question I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Why are you using `find_in_set` instead of `instring` or `locate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive SQL doesn't support Standard SQL POSITION and Teradata's INDEX (don't know why both are used, different syntax to get the same result).

Both can be replaced by LOCATE.

Addionally Standard SQL SUBSTRING is also not implemented in Hive, it's SUBSTR:

```
CASE WHEN (PHOTO_COUNT >0) AND (locate(';', PICTURE_URL)>0) THEN 
 SUBSTR(PICTURE_URL, 1, locate(';', PICTURE_URL)-1)
```

Comment: `cannot recognize input near 'PICTURE_URL' 'FROM' '1' in select expression` in hive 
while executing this line `SUBSTRING(PICTURE_URL FROM 1 FOR locate(';', PICTURE_URL)-1)`

Comment: Ops, another Standard SQL function not known by Hive, I'll fix it

Comment: meanwhile I am also analysing the replacement, let's explore together !

Comment: Hive supports substring and substr, they just both use the same syntax - `substr(<col>,<start>,<end>)` or `substring(<col>,<start>,<end>)`.

Answer (score 0):

the below query might be the equivalent query for the teradata query you have mentioned.

```
SELECT              
 concat(TRIM(BOOK_ID), '_', TRIM(REF_ID)) AS BOOK_REF,
 CASE WHEN (PHOTO_COUNT >0) AND (INSTR(PICTURE_URL,'\;')>0) THEN 
 SUBSTR(split(PICTURE_URL,'\\;')[1],-1)
 ELSE PICTURE_URL
 END AS MAIN_IMAGE FROM GENERIC_BOOKS;
```

tested with the below code samples,

```
create table if not exists generic_books(book_id string, ref_id string, photo_count string, picture_url string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

insert into table generic_books values ("1","1","1","AAA\;BBB"); 

insert into table generic_books values ("a","b","CDB","AAA\;BBB");

/*hive> select * from generic_books;
OK
1       1       CDB     AAA;BBB
a       b       CDB     AAA;BBB
1       1       1       AAA;BBB
*/

hive> SELECT
    >  concat(TRIM(BOOK_ID), '_', TRIM(REF_ID)) AS BOOK_REF,
    >  CASE WHEN (PHOTO_COUNT >0) AND (INSTR(PICTURE_URL,'\;')>0) THEN
    >  SUBSTR(split(PICTURE_URL,'\\;')[0],-1)
    >  ELSE PICTURE_URL
    >  END AS MAIN_IMAGE FROM GENERIC_BOOKS;

/*OK
1_1     AAA;BBB
a_b     AAA;BBB
1_1     A
*/
```

**Note: If you could share the teradata input & output of the query in your question I can update the answer accordingly.**